# Implicit function theorem on vector valued function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

> [image]

Above is implicit function theorem, and here is a special case

> [image]

In second case, $f(y)=(x,z)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, also $F\in\mathbb{R}^2$, how do we find $\partial_y f$ ? I know $\partial_y f=-\frac{\partial_y F}{\partial_y F}$,

but this only apply if $F\in\mathbb{R}$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most general case of the Implicit Function Theorem we have that if $F\colon\mathbb{R}^{n+m}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is such that $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n,f(x_1,\ldots\,x_n))=0$, then
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\\frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial f_m}{\partial x_n}\end{pmatrix} = -\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y_m}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial y_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial y_m}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_n}\\\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\\frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_1} & \cdots & \frac{\partial F_m}{\partial x_n}\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore in this particular example for the functions $F\colon\mathbb{R^3}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ we have
$$D_yf=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix} = -\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial z}\\\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z}\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}\end{pmatrix}$$